# Application running only on pc with visual studio

Tags: c#, c++, build

I've a VS solution which contains two projects, one is c++ and other is GUI in c#. This c# project calls c++ project for calculations. When I'm running this on my machine its running fine in debug mode but when I'm trying to run it on machine without visual studio(debug build) its not able to get c++ dll, but if I build the solution in release mode and then try to run then it runs fine on both the machine. Can someone explain why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are linking to the debug runtimes for the C++ project.

Either set it to release, or set the linker option to not use the debug runtime.

Answer (score 2):

That is because Visual Studio ships with debug versions of the C runtime (`msvcr100d` for example) which are not present on machines without it.